# Real analysis problem.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Given a continuous function $f:[0,2] \to (0,+\infty)$ such that $\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt = \int_1^2 f(t)\,dt = 1$. How can I find a function $g:[0,1] \to [0,2]$ with continuous derivative such that $\int_x^{g(x)} f(t)\, dt = 1$?

I'm seeking a hint to this question.

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: for any $z\in[0,2]$, let $F(z)=\int_{0}^{z}f(t)\,dt$.
 $F(z)$ is a $C^1$ function and it is strictly increasing from $0$ to $1$ on $[0,1]$ and from $1$ to $2$ on $[1,2]$.
Assume that $x\in[0,1]$. The constraint $\int_{x}^{g(x)}f(t)=1$ is equivalent 
to
$$ F(x) = 1-\int_{g(x)}^{2}f(t)\,dt = F(g(x))-1 $$
hence formally $g(x)$ *has* to be picked as 
$$ g(x) = F^{-1}(F(x)+1) $$
and you just have to prove that the RHS is a $C^1$ function with the correct range.
You should have something about the degree of regularity of inverse functions in your arsenal.

Comment: I wonder if there is "other" answer to this question, and the upvote seems too quick. More judgement is needed, and more thought is needed also....

Comment: @DeepSea: well, clearly $g(x)$ cannot be anything else than $F^{-1}(F(x)+1)$, but maybe there are more efficient approaches for proving that such thing is a $C^1$ function (without writing $g(x)$ down in a explicit way).

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x) = x+1$. We prove: $\int_{x}^{x+1} f(t)dt=1$. Indeed, $h'(x) = 0$, thus $h(x) = h(0) = 1$, whereas $h(x) = \int_{x}^{x+1} f(t)dt$.

Comment: $h'(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$. Why is this $0$ for every $x$?

Comment: Such $g(x)$ does not work if $f(x)$ equals $(2-\varepsilon)x+\varepsilon$ over $[0,1]$, $2$ over $[1,3/2-\varepsilon]$ and quickly decreases to $\varepsilon$ on $[3/2-\varepsilon,2]$.