# Prove that there is a function $g: [0,1] \rightarrow [1,2]$ of class $C^{1}$, such that $\int_{x}^{g(x)} f(t) dt=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, riemann-integration

Let $f: [0,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}^{\ast}$ be a continuous function such that $\int_ {0}^{1} f(t) dt = \int_ {1}^{2}  f(t) dt = 1$. Prove that there is a function $g: [0,1] \rightarrow [1,2]$ of class $C^{1}$, such that $\int_{x}^{g(x)} f(t) dt=1$.

Can anybody help me? Can I conclude that the function is periodic? or symmetrical in the range $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$. What can I get out of it?

Comment: You can use "mean value theorems of integrals"

Comment: What does this theorem say?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2706390/42969 – both found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_%7Bx%7D%5E%7Bg(x)%7D%20f(t)%20dt%3D1%24&p=1)